# Linker file update in microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded

could you please help me to write linker file (in high level and not particular to any mcu) for below code.

```
/*Global variable*/

#define adc_start
int a,b,c;
int d=56, e=22;
const int x=23,y=44;
static int z;
static int t=99;
#define adc_end

void add()
{
    int e,f,g;
    e=f+g;
}

main()
{
    int f;

    f=add();
    return 0;
}
```

/*
MemMap.h */

```
/*Please help here*/
#define adc_start
#define adc_end
    
    
    
;;;;
```

/* Linker file */

```
/*Please help here*/
MEMORY
{




}

SECTIONS
{

{
}>RAM

}
```

> Note: Its just high level, if I miss something in code you can update,
> I want to understand RAM, ROM,BSS, STACK, HEAP in inker section how
> they mapping.
>
> especially I don't how to describe macros in memmap.h Related to code,
> data, heap, stack

Comment: The code is irrelevant and a linker script is always specific to a particular MCU since they have different memory maps and may execute from ROM or require code to be transferred to RAM for execution.  The compiler/linker will havwever expect specific sections to be declared (.bss, .data .text for example).  They will all be in the default linker script for your platform in any event.  You seldom need to create one from scratch, you normally only need customise it for specific memory support and special requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Linker script does not dependent on your code (outside of special memory tricks)
It usually looks like that :

```
_estack = ORIGIN(DTCMRAM) + LENGTH(DTCMRAM);

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x1000 ;   /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0xD000 ;  /* required amount of stack */

MEMORY
{
  DTCMRAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 128K
  ITCMRAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  RAM_D1    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x24000000,   LENGTH = 512K
  RAM_D2    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x30000000,   LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D3    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x38000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 1024K
}

SECTIONS
{
  ...
}
```

The addresses you see in `MEMORY` are **defined by your hardware** (memory mapping). It's an example for a STM32H7 microcontroller, it will **NOT** work with your hardware 
You should NOT try to write it yourself, the microcontroller distributor should distribute it with package/example code.
If you still want to do it yourself, find the addresses in the MCU datasheet and fill the segments you need 
 The symbols declared in linker script are related to your startup file, a good example is the first section :

```
.isr_vector :
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
  . = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH
```

More [here](http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-ld-en-3/simple-example.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how to link my code, data, stack to linker file. I have written variable a, b, c, d, e, f, g by using memap.h

Comment: It's the job of the compiler linker to dispatch your variables in your memory sections. You just have to define section in linker script (and eventual init in startup file) and your compiler do all the job. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with memap.h but it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing AUTOSAR like MemoryMapping.

You should take a look into

[AUTOSAR SWS MemoryMapping](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_MemoryMapping.pdf)

[AUTOSAR SWS CompilerAbstraction](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_CompilerAbstraction.pdf)

There are also certain standard "sections" described for variables and code. They also have certain init-policies or safety (QM, ASIL_A, ASIL_B) and alignment options (8,16,32,PTR,UNSPECIFIED, .. ).

In the end, your code should look then like this:

```
#define ADC_START_SEC_VAR_FAST
#include "MemMap.h"
// Variables with "fast access",
// which should be placed close to the core, e.g. DTCM
static uint32 Adc_FastVariable;

#define ADC_STOP_SEC_VAR_FAST
#include "MemMap.h"

#define ADC_START_SEC_VAR_SLOW
#include "MemMap.h"
// Variables with "normal/slow access",
// which could be placed in e.g. L3 RAM
static uint32 Adc_FastVariable;

#define ADC_STOP_SEC_VAR_FAST
#include "MemMap.h"
```

Depending on the `#define`, the following `#include "MemMap.h"` will then be replaced the configured section `#pragma` at this location.

If you change the section name (e.g. `.adc_fast.bss` instead of the default `.bss`) the compiler will create a new input section and place the variable there, which the linker will then try to place into the output-section you defined in the linker script to be used.

```
SECTIONS {
    GROUP {
        .fast.bss {
            *(.adc_fast.bss)
            *(.pwm_fast.bss)
        }
    } > DTCM0;
    GROUP {
        .bss {
            *(.adc_slow.bss)
            *(.pwm_slow.bss)
        }
    } > RAM_L3;
}
```